# Problem on order of a group

Tags: group-theory

How many elements of order $2$ are there in the group of order $16$ generated by $a$ and  $b$ such that the order of $a$ is $8$,the order of $b$ is $2$ and $bab^{-1}=a^{-1}$.

Comment: Good question...

Comment: The elements are uniquely expressible as $a^nb^k$ with $n\in\{0,\cdots,7\}$ and $k\in\{0,1\}$. Prove this first. Then start calculating the order of each.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 3):

The relations $a^{k}=1, \, b^2=1, \, ba=a^{-1}b$ define the dihedral group of order $2k$.

In this case the order is $16$, so you have *nine* involutions: the eight reflexions $b$, $ab, \ldots, a^7b$ and the central involution $a^4$.